# Getting error after upgrading to nextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, node.js, build, next.js13, unexpected-token

I have upgraded my project to Next.js 13.5.4, but I am continuously getting below errors,
[image]
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' (at framework-4c4589c9e2596a2b.js:1:65295)
[coinSlug]-c0e6d6fef17361b1.js:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at [coinSlug]-c0e6d6fef17361b1.js:1:65698)

can you please help me to solve these errors,

Here is the package versions I am using,
"dependencies": {
"@rehooks/local-storage": "^2.4.5",
"@tippyjs/react": "^4.2.6",
"array-move": "^4.0.0",
"axios": "^1.5.1",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
"bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
"cookie": "^0.5.0",
"cookies-next": "^4.0.0",
"dayjs": "^1.11.10",
"downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
"highcharts": "^11.1.0",
"highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.1",
"html-to-image": "^1.11.11",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"local-storage": "^2.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"next": "^13.5.4",
"next-useragent": "^2.8.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
"react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^8.0.0",
"react-cookie": "^6.1.1",
"react-datepicker": "^4.19.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-ga": "^3.3.1",
"react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
"react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
"react-highcharts": "^16.1.0",
"react-icons": "^4.11.0",
"react-joyride": "^2.6.0",
"react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.6.0",
"react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
"react-loading-skeleton": "^3.3.1",
"react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
"react-table": "^7.8.0",
"react-tabs": "^6.0.2",
"react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
"react-tradingview-widget": "^1.3.2",
"react-ts-tradingview-widgets": "^1.2.0",
"react-twitter-embed": "^4.0.4",
"sharp": "^0.32.6",
"use-ssr": "^1.0.25"
},

I am currently running on NodeJS version:

20.9.0

I have researched a lot about this issue on Internet but nothing gets worked.

Thank you